# When opening reputation graph on chrome with a touchscreen, it only responds to touchevents, not clicks

Tags: bug, reputation-history, google-chrome

I noticed today for the first time, after for a long time I had clicking on the graph in the reputation tab not working at all (on chrome on my laptop running linux, while it works and worked perfectly on my desktop with same chrome and fedora versions), that it actually responds to touch events. It only does not seem to get any mouse click thru.

This was happening already well before the new profile page was deployed.

Comment: This should be posted on [MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com) if it is a cross-site issue.

Comment: @PatrickHofman good point, I'll verify tonight with my laptop on unix&linux and report back

Comment: @PatrickHofman yep, same behaviour on un unix&linux and vi&vim; should i ask on mse as well, or let the post be migrated?

Comment: You have two options: delete and repost on MSE. Or flag and ask a mod to migrate.

Comment: I'll go for the flag.

Comment: It is probably a bug in highcharts.js. Using chrome inspector i see that any histogram bar has two attached event listeners on my laptop: `mouseout` and `touchstart`. While on the desktop they are `mouseout` and `mouseover`.

Comment: Posting bug reports here is fine; this doesn't need to be migrated. If you'd *prefer* to write it up on MSE, just delete this and re-post - but first, please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/bug/info